# Change mocked getResponse .net

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a test that get some devices states from an endpoint. I have that response mocked and get the info correctly. The test that I want to implement must get this info and after a while get that info again and check if it's different to throw an event. The problem is that I can't change the mocked response in my test. This is what I tried.

Implementation of mocked WebRequest.

```
class TestWebRequestCreate : IWebRequestCreate
{

    public TestWebRequest testWebRequest { get; set; }

    public WebRequest Create(Uri uri)
    {
        WebRequest webRequest;
        if (testWebRequest == null)
        {
            webRequest = new TestWebRequest(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Testing response");
        }
        else
        {
            webRequest = testWebRequest;
        }
        return webRequest;
    }
}

class TestWebRequest : WebRequest
{
    public HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode { get; set; }
    public Stream responseMessage;

    /// <summary>
    ///  Initialize a new instance of <see cref="TestWebRequest"/>
    ///  with the response to return
    /// </summary>
    public TestWebRequest(HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode, string responseMessage)
    {
        this.httpStatusCode = httpStatusCode;
        this.responseMessage = StreamFromString(responseMessage);

    }

    public override WebResponse GetResponse()
    {
        MemoryStream responseCopy = new MemoryStream();
        //Stream responseCopy = new MemoryStream();
        responseMessage.Position = 0;
        responseMessage.CopyTo(responseCopy);
        //Reset position after reading Streams
        responseCopy.Position = 0;
        Mock<HttpWebResponse> mockHttpWebResponse = new Mock<HttpWebResponse>();
        mockHttpWebResponse.Setup(r => r.StatusCode).Returns(httpStatusCode);
        mockHttpWebResponse.Setup(r => r.GetResponseStream()).Returns(responseCopy);
        return mockHttpWebResponse.Object;
    }
```

After this in my test I do this:

```
        public void DeviceChangedEvent_WhenDeviceHaveChanged_EventIsThrown()
    {
        string uri = new UriBuilder(TESTHOSTPREFFIX, TESTCORRECTHOST, TESTPORT, TESTDEVICEENDPOINT).ToString();
        bool wasThrown = false;
        m_deviceRetriever.Init(m_serviceProvider);
        m_deviceRetriever.Start();
        m_deviceRetriever.DeviceChangeEvent += (DeviceRetrieverOnDeviceChangeEvent, args) =>
        {
            wasThrown = true;
        };

        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        //Change device XML to simulate the change
        var namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(m_correctMockedXmlDevice.NameTable);
        namespaceManager.AddNamespace("ps", "http://www.hp.com/ps/fall15");
        XmlNode printheadIdNode = m_correctMockedXmlDevices.SelectSingleNode("/ps:DevicesStatus/DeviceSlotCollection/DeviceSlot/SlotId", namespaceManager);
        deviceIdNode.InnerText = "Changed";
        m_testWebRequestCreateCorrectDevices = null;
        m_testWebRequestCreateCorrectDevices = new TestWebRequestCreate
        {
            testWebRequest = new TestWebRequest(HttpStatusCode.OK, m_correctMockedXmlDevices.InnerXml)
        };

        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        //We give some time to get the new state of printheads
        Assert.IsTrue(wasThrown);
    }
}
```

Before the test I'm preparing it creating this

```
    private void CreateCorrectDevicesMockEndpoint()
    {
        string uri = new UriBuilder(TESTHOSTPREFFIX, TESTCORRECTHOST, TESTPORT, TESTPRINTHEADSENDPOINT).ToString();
        m_testWebRequestCreateCorrectDevices = new TestWebRequestCreate();
        m_correctMockedXmlDevices = new XmlDocument();
        m_correctMockedXmlDevices.Load("pathToXMLFile");
        m_testWebRequestCreateCorrectDevices.testWebRequest = new TestWebRequest(HttpStatusCode.OK, m_correctMockedXmlPrintheads.InnerXml);
        WebRequest.RegisterPrefix(uri, m_testWebRequestCreateCorrectDevices);
    }
```

EDIT:
And my setup for the tests is initializing all my necessary dependencies.

```
    public void SetUp()
    {
        m_serviceProvider = new ServiceProvider();

        m_serviceProvider.Add<ILogger>(new Mock<ILogger>().Object);

        m_deviceRetriever = new DeviceRetriever();

        m_connectivitySettings = new ConnectivitySettings() { IpAddress = TESTCORRECTHOST };
        m_serviceProvider.Add<ConnectivitySettings>(m_connectivitySettings);

        CreateCorrectDevicesMockEndpoint();
    }
```

I'm not getting any error, the problem is that the XML returned by my mock is not changed. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please go through your question and clarify it. As it is now its very difficult to help you. For example: you dont show where `m_deviceRetriever` is declared and initialized.

Comment: @Domysee thank you for your advice. I added the code but I think the problem is basically in the mock

Comment: How does the code that throws the exception actually retrieve the response?  It looks like you are creating Mocks in you test code, but not actually passing them anywhere.

Comment: @forsvarir I'm using the getResponse function and it's working perfectly because I get the mocked information. The problem is when I change the mock response as shown above I'm retrieving the old response

Comment: My point is, that the code you've posted seems to be missing the critical step of actually calling `GetResponse`.  As I understand your code, at some point in your test, you assign  a field in your test fixture to a new request and then sleep, waiting for something (presumably some kind of background thread calls `GetResponse` and marks `wasThrown` in your `m_deviceRetriever`.  How does *whatever calls GetResponse* get access to the field containing the new request which will return the new mock.  If it uses the old request object, it's still going to get the old mocked value...

Comment: @forsvarir thanks for your time. It's not posted here and it's my error. I am calling getResponse in a different thread doing polling every 500 ms. When I debug I can verify that I'm calling the getResponse method. The problem is that I'm getting the oldvalues and not the changed mock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've said in my comments, I believe your problem is in the code you're not showing us.  The mocking you're setting up works fine, however it relies on your calling `GetResponse` on the correct instance of your `TestWebRequest`.  My belief is that however you are polling, you are not updating the instance of the `TestWebRequestCreate` that the poller is using, as a result it is simply creating another instance of the `TestWebRequest` setup with the original mocking.  Below is an example, complete test that illustrates that your mocking works and can be accessed from a different thread and work as expected.

```
bool wasThrown = false;
IWebRequestCreate m_testWebRequestCreateCorrectDevices = null;

[TestMethod]
public void TestThreadedWebRequest()
{
    const string errorResponse = "Some Error Text";
    m_testWebRequestCreateCorrectDevices = new TestWebRequestCreate();
    var uri = new Uri(@"http:\\www.stackoverflow.com");
    wasThrown = false;

    var thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var creator = m_testWebRequestCreateCorrectDevices;
                if (creator != null)
                {
                    var message = creator.Create(uri); 
                    var response = new StreamReader(message.GetResponse()
                                                      .GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                    if (response == errorResponse)
                    {
                        wasThrown = true;
                        break;
                     }
                }
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        });

    thread.Start();

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Assert.AreEqual(false, wasThrown);


    m_testWebRequestCreateCorrectDevices = null;
    m_testWebRequestCreateCorrectDevices = new TestWebRequestCreate
    {
        testWebRequest = new TestWebRequest(HttpStatusCode.OK, errorResponse)
    };

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

    Assert.AreEqual(true, wasThrown);

    if (!thread.Join(1000))
    {
        thread.Abort();
    }
}
```

Note, in your existing code, you set `m_testWebRequestCreateCorrectDevices` to the instance of the new message creator that creates the correctly mocked response.  This is unlikely to be enough unless your production code is referencing this variable (which is the case in my example above).

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem was a bad reference. Your code helped me a lot to find it. THANKS!